# How to Create UIImage with kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA formatted Buffer using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext

We are creating UIImage from a buffer using following code

```
let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

    let cgImage0 =   context.makeImage()  
    let uiImage0 =  UIImage(cgImage: cgImage0!)
```

The problem is we can create color image buffer using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput() only with kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA format which is the most similar format to kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA

At some point we need UIImage and we needed to convert buffer to UIImage and because UIImage is RGBA formatted colors has become distorted.

How can we get UIImage from buffer in kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA format.

Answer (score 6):

By making

```
   var bitmapInfo  = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
    bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
```

instead of

```
   var bitmapInfo  = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
```

But getting this from Apple document is very hard.

Comment: Life saver! Why does apple make this so hard to figure out??